# How to remove items from list and make items join

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list which has numbers, but because its appended to a list using for loop it has '\n' and I don't know how to remove it.

the list looks like this

```
['3', '7', '4', '5', '5', '9', '2', '2', '7', '\n', '4', '3', '7', '1', '5', '9', '4', '3', '0', '\n', '3', '7', '2', '4', '1', '0', '2', '7', '5', '\n', '7', '8', '4', '5', '1', '6', '2', '5', '7', '\n', '2', '8', '0', '6', '6', '1', '1', '2', '3', '\n', '9', '3', '5', '6', '8', '3', '8', '7', '1', '\n', '6', '7', '5', '5', '4', '7', '4', '8', '6']
```

I want to remove ' ' and '\n' so it would look like this

```
[374559227,437159430,372410275,784516257,280661123,935683871,675547486]
```

Comment: Where does that weird list come from to begin with? Can you read it differently somehow so you don't need to post-process it like this…?

Comment: split the list by `'\n'`, turn each number to an int and join them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join to a string and split the newlines:

```
l = [
    '3', '7', '4', '5', '5', '9', '2', '2', '7', '\n', '4', '3', '7', '1', '5',
    '9', '4', '3', '0', '\n', '3', '7', '2', '4', '1', '0', '2', '7', '5', '\n',
    '7', '8', '4', '5', '1', '6', '2', '5', '7', '\n', '2', '8', '0', '6', '6',
    '1', '1', '2', '3', '\n', '9', '3', '5', '6', '8', '3', '8', '7', '1', '\n',
    '6', '7', '5', '5', '4', '7', '4', '8', '6'
]
print([int(x) for x in ''.join(l).split('\n')])
>>> [374559227, 437159430, 372410275, 784516257, 280661123, 935683871, 675547486]
```

Comment: Just run this code and got the error - `ValueError:` invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''   Is something missing here?   Believe there is `trailing \n` cause this error.

Comment: @Daniel Hao: Probably you got an empty string in your list. The code snippet I've posted works fine using Py2.7 and 3.9

Comment: I found it - the very last `n` is the culprit - which should `not` be there. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> lst = ['3', '7', '4', '5', '5', '9', '2', '2', '7', '\n', '4', '3', '7', '1', '5', '9', '4', '3', '0', '\n', '3', '7', '2', '4', '1', '0', '2', '7', '5', '\n', '7', '8', '4', '5', '1', '6', '2', '5', '7', '\n', '2', '8', '0', '6', '6', '1', '1', '2', '3', '\n', '9', '3', '5', '6', '8', '3', '8', '7', '1', '\n', '6', '7', '5', '5', '4', '7', '4', '8', '6']    
>>> [int(''.join(digits)) for is_number, digits in groupby(lst, lambda x: x != '\n') if is_number]
[374559227, 437159430, 372410275, 784516257, 280661123, 935683871, 675547486]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function

```
from functools import reduce
lst = ['3', '7', '4', '5', '5', '9', '2', '2', '7', '\n', '4', '3', '7', '1', '5', '9', '4', '3', '0', '\n', '3', '7', '2', '4', '1', '0', '2', '7', '5', '\n', '7', '8', '4', '5', '1', '6', '2', '5', '7', '\n', '2', '8', '0', '6', '6', '1', '1', '2', '3', '\n', '9', '3', '5', '6', '8', '3', '8', '7', '1', '\n', '6', '7', '5', '5', '4', '7', '4', '8', '6']
lst_result = [int(n) for n in reduce(lambda x, y: f"{x}{y}", lst).split('\n')]
```

Output:

```
[374559227, 437159430, 372410275, 784516257, 280661123, 935683871, 675547486]
```